# Custom field saves, for all entries, instead of wanted data a number that is not in original data

Tags: custom-fields, data-import

I'm having an odd problem with a custom field within a custom data set.
The field is made for personal identification number, data type is integer and it's a single line input field.
Every time I enter the data either manually or through import (careful about choosing corresponding fields) upon clicking the save button instead of saving the wanted number it saves a completely different number that's not in my data (it's always the same number).
I even tried to delete the custom field (with corresponding data), then create it again and manually add it back but nothing.

Using WP

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that I had to delete the set and re-create it again in order for it to work like it should. Why, I've no idea.